# setting style properties from jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a script that adds a left and right border to a button in a line of 3 buttons when that button is clicked, and keep it with no border otherwise. The code I have so far is:

```
$("#popular").click(function(){  
    clearBorders();
    //make borders here (this works)   
}); 

$("#suggestions").click(function(){    
    clearBorders();
    //make borders here (this works)   
}); 

$("recent").click(function(){    
    clearBorders();
    //make borders here (this works)  
}); 

function clearBorders(){
    $('popular').css("border", "solid");
    $('suggestions').css("border", "none");
    $('recent').css("border", "none");
}    
});
```

I am able to create the borders fine, but for some reason the clearborders method is not working. I know the function is being called because if I put an alert at the beginning of it, it shows up. Why won't this function work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selectors are missing the leading id (#) or class (.) designator symbol in your clearBorders() function

Comment: either the id selector # OR the class selector .

Comment: @dormisher true. Went with # based on the other selectors where it was present. I'll amend the answer

Answer (score 1):

I did a test of this and you need to do a $("document").ready(function(){}); wrapper. I had already adjusted to use classes so you might or might not work with ids. At least the test case below didn't work for me until I handled the document.ready.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".popular").click(function(){ 
        clearBorders(); }
    ); 

    $(".suggestions").click(function(){         
        clearBorders();
        // make borders here (this works)   
    });

    $(".recent").click(function(){    
    clearBorders();
    //make borders here (this works)  
    }); }
);
    function clearBorders(){
        $('.popular').css("border", "1px solid red");
        $('.suggestions').css("border", "1px solid red");
        $('.recent').css("border", "1px solid red");
    };   
    </script>
```

rich